# Use jQuery to Add Class to Input Element

Tags: jquery, addclass

```
<input type="search" class="facetwp-search" value="" placeholder="filter keyword">
```

I want to use jQuery to add a class of 'form-control' in a WordPress theme

Using this, it does not work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('facetwp-search').addClass('form-control');
});
```

What is missing?

Comment: hah .. "what is missing?" DOT man :) only dot define css class in your case

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a period in the jQuery selector.  To select objects by class, use a period in the selector as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.facetwp-search').addClass('form-control'); // not $('facetwp-search')...
});
```

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/3tx1cb5b/

Comment: Tried that.  Still a no go.  I'm wrapping in a no-conflict wrapper because it's WordPress, but that shouldn't affect anything.

Comment: See fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/3tx1cb5b/
It does work.  Perhaps an error in the style sheet?

Comment: @lime your code have to work with fix how benjamin sayed. If you have any other problem pls give more info

Comment: I copied benjamins code exactly.  When viewing source, the class is not added. I am not sure what more information to give.  I'm using WordPress, running script in a no-conflict wrapper.  The input is being created from a plugin.

Comment: What browser are you using?  You should be able to look at the element in a debug mode and see that the class is added. Also look for console errors. If the page is live, include a link and we can check it out too.